# How to specify 'selecteditemtemplate' in EditableComboBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a combo box with the property IsEditable set to true. That was I can do basics search within. However, now that it's on, the text that appears is either the toString or the DisplayMemberPath and no longer the itemTemplate I had in this combo box.

Is there a way to put back the Item Template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use ExpressionBlend to get the internal template of your EditableComboBox and then do the desired changes in the default template.

Comment: I see, Isn't there any simplier way to do this ? I get that it might not be that hard but still...